# Inno Setup "Out of Sytem resources" on background image

Tags: bitmap, inno-setup

I'm creating an installer with Inno Setup and I want to set a .bmp image as background, but the "Out of System resources" keeps popping up randomly (sometimes it pops up, sometimes it doesn't) in the Welcome page and in the "Setup completed" (basically the only pages with the image).

[image: Error screenshot]

I tried different sizes and bit depths but that doesn't solve it (and it never says "Invalid Bitmap image", so I don't think that's the problem).

Do you guys have more info about this?

Comment: What size is your bitmap?  What color depth?  You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: As i said in the post, i tried most of the _resolutions/color depths_ that I found on the [Inno website](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardimagefile), like for example 246*386 24 bits.

Comment: What does your script look like?  I created a simple script and a BMP of 248*386 24 bits and couldn't make the error happen?  You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: Run you setup using the log parameter from the command line. Then show us the log. At least look for where the error is reported in the log.

Comment: Please see this discussion: http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup/msg105110.html. I assume you are using non-Unicode. Consider trying the v6 beta available on the website.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Thanks man! That solved it! I wrote a short answer for the archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! (thanks to Andrew Truckle for the hint).

> Please see this discussion: news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup/msg105110.html. I assume you are using non-Unicode. Consider trying the v6 beta available on the website.

This error shows up in non_Unicode builds of Inno Setup (I guess it's an encoding problem?).

Downloading the Unicode one solved it!

Comment: Glad I was able to help you. Comments might be removed at any time so I suggest you provide a link to the discussion I supplied and maybe extract one or two comments that are pertinent to the reason for the issue. Put those in your answer.